# Android, Creating an arraylist of .mp3 files?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to create an arraylist of .mp3 files and strings. If a string in the arraylist is called by a randomnumber than a specific mp3 file will play. Could I make an arraylist filled with both .mp3 files and Strings so they can be called simultaneously or would I make seperate arrayLists. Or maybe not even use an ArrayList of .mp3 files? Thank You.

```
ArrayList<String? words = new ArrayList<String>
words.add("Hello World");

//On Button Click
//Generates randomNumber Integer
//randomNumber=1
//SetText to "Hello World" and play .mp3 that says "Hello World" simultaneously and put thread to sleep for .mp3 length
```

How is the best way to achieve this with least amount of hardcoding?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [Map](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map.html) that correlates the Strings to the MP3 file paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom arraylist of objects as follows..

```
public class SongInfo
{
    String songName;
    String songPath;


    public SongInfo(String songName,String songPath){
        this.songName = songName;
        this.songPath = songPath;

    }
}

ArrayList<SongInfo> customSongList = new ArrayList<SongInfo>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your own Song Object and pickup songs from it randomly

```
public class Player {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player player = new Player();
        //populate music in your arrayList
        List<Song> album = player.populateMusicList();
        //play
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            player.play(album);
        }
    }

    public void play(List<Song> album) {
        System.out.println("playing --" + album.get(this.fetchMusicRandomly(album)));
    }

    private int fetchMusicRandomly(List<Song> album) {
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, album.size());
    }

    private List<Song> populateMusicList() {
        List<Song> musicBucket = new ArrayList<Song>();
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-1", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-2", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-3", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-4", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-5", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-6", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-7", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-8", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-9", "pathtomp3File"));
        musicBucket.add(new Song("musicName-10", "pathtomp3File"));
        return musicBucket;
    }

    class Song {

        public Song(String name, String pathToMp3) {
            this.name = name;
            this.pathToMp3 = pathToMp3;
        }
        String name;
        String pathToMp3;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getPathToMp3() {
            return pathToMp3;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            result.append(" {Name: " + name + " }");
            result.append(" {Path To Mp3file: " + pathToMp3);
            result.append("}");
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
}
```